# Add post location with mile radius allowing search

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, search, geo-data

I have a custom post type (CPT) called directory. Within this CPT there are taxonomies such as builder, plumber, painter etc.

I would like to be able to add a location and a distance radius where the service is available.

**Example 1** 

A post (A) has a location of London and a mile radius of 70 miles.

If a user searches for builder in cambridge then post A will appear in the search results.

**Example 2**

A post (A) has a location of London and a mile radius of 70 miles.

If a user searches for builder in Liverpool then post A will **not** appear in the search results.

The search fields have to search a taxonomy and the distance.

I've looked at the below plugins but not had much luck.

https://geomywp.com/
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/business-directory-plugin/
https://locatewp.com/
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-store-locator/

I think this is going down the bespoke route but if anyone can help out it will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you say location, do you literally mean the location is the string `"London"`? Or do you mean you have a latitude and longitude location that is inside London? If you're looking for something that knows the boundaries of London the area, and can project them out 70 miles and do a search in that area, then you'll be extremely lucky to find something. Even the big players in the market wouldn't do that

Comment: Looking at the plugins mentioned above, I believe they use the Google maps API to located the place and distance.

Comment: an external api is only part of it. It allows for getting Lat/Lng values from a street or region, but you can't hit an api every time you need to know if post A is near post B or within region C.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I did think this is going down a bespoke route rather than seeing if there was any plugins out there

Comment: Any luck with this?